# Let $f(n) = 3n^{2} + 7n + 12$ and $g(n) = n^{3}$. Want to understand this..

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f(n) = 3n^{2} +  7n + 12$ and $g(n) = n^{3}$. Which one of the following is a correct statement?

A) $f(n) = O(g(n)).$

B) $f(n) = \Omega (g(n))$.

C) $f(n) = \Theta (g(n))$.

D) All of the above are correct.

E) None of the above is correct.

Can someone please help me with this, to better understand it? This is one of my exam question that we had, and I guess luckily on it, but I want to know how it is done. I read on definitions that suppose to help me with it, but they confuse me...is there a easy way to quickly get a answer, say if I'm taking a final exam, would there be  a quicker way determining the answer? Or if someone can explain this to me, that be great. Thanks

Comment: The definitions are clearly set out in many places, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation What is the difficulty? The example is an easy case.

Comment: Does the amount of exponents matter when trying to proof it? I get more frustrated when the exponents don't match. How do I solve it in this case?

Comment: One alternative says "$f$ and $g$ are (roughly) equal in value", one says "$f$ is at least as large as $g$" and the last one says "$f$ is smaller than or equal to $g$ in value". This is very simplified, and in arbitrary order, but that's the gist of it. I assume you can tell which of my formulations is the correct one.

Comment: Ok take A), which is true. We have to show that we can find a constant $M$ such that $|f(n)|<M|g(n)|$ for all sufficiently large $n$. That is obviously true because $g(n)$ has higher degree than $f(n)$. For example, take $n>22$, then $n^3>22n^2=3n^2+7n^2+12n^2>3n^2+7n+12$.

Comment: Oh I see, and for Omega its f(n) greater than g(n), which is not true in question case. I am still skeptical about Theta, some definitions refer to it as "eqaul" to. Does refer f(n) equal to g(n)? Which then mean it is also not true for C). Thus leaving A) as our only solution.

Comment: For C) the ratio has to be bounded, so that there are positive $k,k'$ with $kg(n)<f(n)<k'g(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$. That is clearly not true here (you can find $k'$ but not $k$.

Comment: Oh ok, that gives me a good amount of understanding of it. Thanks!